# Vector direction

Tags: vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

I have a vector in the `2nd Coordinate` of the Cartesian plane. I want to know that how can I find out the direction of the vector that whether it is towards the origin or away from it whether its in increasing direction of `Y-Coordinate` or in the decreasing direction of `Y-Coordinate`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) If you only know the second coordinate and not the first, you cannot know if the vector points to or away the origin.

2) If you have a function that describes the y coordinate (but you didnt tell which on it is), you can know if it grows or not in the y-coordinate